# remove multiple substrings inside a string

Tags: python, regex

Here's hoping somebody can shed some light on this question because it has me stumped. I have a string that looks like this:

```
s = "abcdef [[xxxx xxx|ghijk]] lmnop [[qrs]] tuv [[xx xxxx|wxyz]] 0123456789"
```

I want this result:

```
abcdef ghijk lmnop qrs tuv wxyz 0123456789
```

Having reviewed numerous questions and answers here, the closest I have come to a solution is:

```
s = "abcdef [[xxxx xxx|ghijk]] lmnop [[qrs]] tuv [[xx xxxx|wxyz]] 0123456789"
s = re.sub('\[\[.*?\|', '', s)
s = re.sub('[\]\]]', '', s)
--> abcdef ghijk lmnop wxyz 0123456789
```

Since not every substring within double brackets contains a pipe, the re.sub removes everything from '[[' to next '|' instead of checking within each set of double brackets.

Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you please describe the discriminating factor, i.e., why those particular substrings?

Comment: Try using raw strings for your regular expressions, like `r'\[\[.*?\|'`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 in my text whenever a pipe occurs between a set of double brackets, everything before the pipe is a description I don't need in the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "abcdef [[xxxx xxx|ghijk]] lmnop [[qrs]] tuv [[xx xxxx|wxyz]] 0123456789"
>>> re.sub(r'(\[\[[^]]+?\|)|([\[\]])', '', s)
'abcdef ghijk lmnop qrs tuv wxyz 0123456789'
```

This searches for and removes the following two items:

1. Two opening brackets followed by a bunch of stuff that isn't a closing bracket followed by a pipe.
2. Opening or closing brackets.

Comment: just ran your solution through a sample of my file and it worked with every entry. Comes after a lot of frustration on the issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
In [187]: re.sub(r'([\[|\]])|((?<=\[)\w+\s+\w+(?=|))', '', s)
Out[187]: 'abcdef ghijk lmnop qrs tuv wxyz 0123456789'
```

Comment: Should have specified that the x's between '[[' and the '|' represent a substring unknown to me. How can I alter your suggested regex to include any character?

Answer (score 1):

I purpose you a contrary method, instead of remove it you can just catch patterns you want. I think this way can make your code more semantics.

There are two patterns you wish to catch:

1. Case: words outside `[[...]]`

   Pattern: Any words are either leaded by `']] '` or trailed by `' [['`.

   Regex: `(?<=\]\]\s)\w+|\w+(?=\s\[\[)`
2. Case: words inside `[[...]]`

   Pattern: Any words are trailed by `']]'`

   Regex: `\w+(?=\]\])`

Example code

```
1 #!/usr/bin/env python
2 import re
3
4 s = "abcdef [[xxxx xxx|ghijk]] lmnop [[qrs]] tuv [[xx xxxx|wxyz]] 0123456789    "
5
6 p = re.compile('(?<=\]\]\s)\w+|\w+(?=\s\[\[)|\w+(?=\]\])')
7 print p.findall(s)
```

Result:

```
['abcdef', 'ghijk', 'lmnop', 'qrs', 'tuv', 'wxyz', '0123456789']
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general regex using built-in `re` module you can use follwing regex that used [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!\[\[)\b([\w]+)\b(?!\|)|\[\[([^|]*)\]\]
```

you can use `re.finditer` to get the desire result :

```
>>> g=re.finditer(r'(?<!\[\[)\b([\w]+)\b(?!\|)|(?<=\[\[)[^|]*(?=\]\])',s)
>>> [j.group() for j in g]
['abcdef', 'ghijk', 'lmnop', 'qrs', 'tuv', 'wxyz', '0123456789']
```

The preceding regex contains from 2 part one is :

```
(?<=\[\[)[^|]*(?=\]\])
```

which match any combinations of word characters that not followed by `|` and not precede by `[[`.

the second part is :

```
\[\[([^|]*)\]\]
```

that will match any thing between 2 brackets except `|`.